# docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? Linux Bash Shell on windows 10

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-10

I am new to Docker. I'm trying to work with it on windows. 
I have Windows 10 Family so I installed Linux Bash Shell. 
When I run this command:

```
$ docker run hello-world
```

I get :
`docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`.
And when I run

```
$ systemctl status docker
```

I get

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate
```

Comment: How did you install Docker on Windows? Did you install Docker Desktop? Or Docker Toolbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you wont be able to use docker in Windows 10 `family`, since docker Desktop requires specific Windows version, as said in [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/).

> System Requirements
>
> Windows 10 64-bit: Pro, Enterprise, or Education (Build 15063 or later).

What you can try is to run linux-based virtual machine on you Windows host, and run docker inside of it. But even if you succeeded, you will lose all advantages of the docker in resources consumption.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone using WSL2 and seeing an identical error message, look at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/457#issuecomment-511495846

Powershell

```
wsl -l -v

  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Running         2
```

Ubuntu

```
$ docker run hello-world

docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

$ systemctl status docker

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.

$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker start

 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                                                         [ OK ]

 $ sudo docker run hello-world

 Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
 latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
 b8dfde127a29: Pull complete
 Digest: sha256:308866a43596e83578c7dfa15e27a73011bdd402185a84c5cd7f32a88b501a24
 Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

 Hello from Docker!
 This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

Comment: Using the command you provided it started but didn't work
```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker start 
 * Starting Docker: docker  [ OK ] 
$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: What about using `sudo`, eg. `sudo docker ps`?

Answer (score 1):

Just run the Docker Daemon with.

```
sudo dockerd &
```

The sudo make it run as super user.

Dockerd is DOCKERDaemon

The single & at the end just make it run in the background.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that from the error message, it states that you are using WSL (Windows Sub-system for Linux Version 1), this version did not have Docker support as it is not a full Linux kernel, but an translation layer between a Linux user-space and then translated to Windows Kernel commands.

Running the `wsl --list -v` command will show you the version you are using:

[image]

You can install WSL version 2, which has a Microsoft provided full Linux Kernel running using Hyper-V infrastructure (but not full Hyper-V).  This way it runs on Windows Home, Education, and Professional.   And here you can run a Linux Instance and the install Docker.

[Windows Subsystem for Linux Installation Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

Comment: Where does the error message "state" WSL1? This is an issue in WSL2 as well, with an identical error message.

Comment: @kevlarr The error message in the OP shows that its not a full operating system (hence WSL1)  WSL2 has a full Linux Kernel -- doesn't give the same error message if I understand correctly

Comment: Ah thanks for clarifying the assumption. The same error message actually is received on WSL2 (at least for me), and it's apparently related to `systemctl` not being available.