# Accessing local docker registry from Skopeo container

Tags: docker, containers, docker-registry, quay.io, skopeo

I have a local docker registry on my mac and I want to be able to perform this type of command:

docker run quay.io/skopeo/stable inspect

Tried to use

```
docker run quay.io/skopeo/stable inspect docker-daemon:<image>
```

(docker-daemon will use the local registry)

> Error loading image from docker engine: Cannot connect to the Docker
> daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

I guess the error is coming because the docker container I am running doesn't have a local docker registry.

Thanks!

Comment: dockerd is the daemon service for Docker containers because it is not running in the background we're not able to take any actions related to the service, which needs to be restarted.

Comment: Run this : systemctl start docker

Comment: check these posts - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857634/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docke and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60935907/docker-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-t